# Maximum file size for an application when submitting to the app store

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

Is there any limitation for a file size for an application when submitting to the app store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum app size is 2 GB.